# Essbase dataload error

Tags: essbase

I'm on a Windows 10 box using Oracle Essbase Admin Services console 11.1.2.4. When I load data I get an error. My problem is that the dataload.err file will not write to my c:\ drive or any network drive to which I have access. If I manually create the dataload.err file in Windows Explorer and run the load data process, I can watch the dataload.err file disappear. I've tried a different file name and different directories, but it won't save.

Why won't the dataload.err file save? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually getting a warning when you load data? If a data load is completely successful, the `dataload.err` file will not be created (it is deleted). Other than that it sounds like maybe your folders are locked down pretty tight -- you might try setting the path for the file to be in your home folder somewhere.

Comment: I finally figured it out. All the server apps were updated to 11.1.2.4.010 but the EAS was not. I applied the patch to upgrade EAS to 11.1.2.4.010 and the dataload.err file writes to my c:\ drive.

Comment: Wow, good catch. Definitely try to keep all of the component versions in sync. You never know when there will be some weird glitch.